# How do i set a custom scroll speed inside an element in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, scroll

So, im trying to smoothen out and slow down the scroll animation of a div (MUI Container). I was looking a few days online trying to find an answer, but i couldnt find anything that would help... P.S: I dont want a smooth transition onClick or anything like that, i want consistent custom speed of scroll on mouse wheel. Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
function Projects() {
const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);


return (
    <AnimatedPage>
        <Container
            className="projectsCont"
            sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                overflowY: 'auto',
            }}
            id="scrollDiv"
        >
            {Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => (
                <a
                    key={i}
                    href="***"
                    className={`projectsLink ${theme === 'dark' ? 'darkText' : 'lightText'}`}
                    target="_blank"
                >
                    Sample Text
                </a>
            ))}
        </Container>
    </AnimatedPage>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So i got it finally. The thing is i had to preventDefault in scrollHandler function, and then instead of scrolling on mouseWheel up/down, i had to translate the whole div up or down. Now the next problem is getting it to run smooth tho :D
Here's the solution code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let scrollDiv = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');

    function handleScroll(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let deltaY = e.deltaY;

        if (positionY >= maxY && deltaY < 0) {
            setPositionY(positionY => positionY);
        } else if (positionY <= minY && deltaY > 0) {
            setPositionY(positionY => positionY);
        } else {
            setPositionY(positionY => positionY - (deltaY * 0.5));
        }
    }
    scrollDiv.addEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);

    return () => {
        scrollDiv.removeEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);
    };
}, [positionY]);

return (
    <AnimatedPage>
        <Container
            className="projectsCont"
            sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                overflowY: 'auto',
                
            }}
            style={{
                transform: `translate(0%, ${positionY}px)`
            }}
            id="scrollDiv"
        >
            {Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => (
                <a
                    key={i}
                    href="***"
                    className={`projectsLink ${theme === 'dark' ? 'darkText' : 'lightText'}`}
                    target="_blank"
                >
                    Samle text
                </a>
            ))}
        </Container>
    </AnimatedPage>
);
```